# authorization on google appengine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authorization, google-groups

Please, help. How can I validate user's group membership? Only users of a few google groups can access some pages on the site on appengine (python).
[validating group membership](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/c5f95212f27abbd2) gives a negative answer to my question, but it was a year ago, maybe something has changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no Google Groups API, and thus no way to determine if a user is a member of a Google Group.

Comment: But you can share wave on google wave with a google group, calendar with a group, and other things, and it works somehow, what mechanism do they use?

Comment: They use internal APIs that aren't available externally.

Answer (score 0):

May be late but just for others who find this, here's my solution to this:

Create a new AppScript in drive which you then publish as webservice, you can use something like following code to check if a user is in the group or not:

```
// General context variables
var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("xxxx-group-name@googlegroups.com");

function doGet(request) {
var result = {
authorized: group.hasUser(request.parameter.mail)
};
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

After publishing it, you will get a url which you can access, just append ?mail=user@domain.com to query group membership for the specific email address.